# Messed up viewports after locking/suspending my session

Tags: 14.04

If I move some applications to specific viewports (most of the time I move them by focusing and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrow) and then lock/suspend my session (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), all the windows will be back to viewport 1 after unlocking.

Note that I ticked the "Require my password when waking from suspend".

I'm encountering the issue since Ubuntu 13.10, and unfortunately the wasn't resolved in 14.04. How do I let the applications remain on the same viewport as they were after unlocking/resuming from suspend as they were before.

Comment: What desktop manager are you using(unity, gnome, KDE)? Have you installed any customization softwares(compiz, etc)?

Comment: Unity.  To my knowledge, it's just the regular/vanilla installation.  I just used the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) to fine tune hotkeys.

Comment: Can you check if ccsm is not the culprit by temporarily removing it(if you don't have too many configurations)? Are you using a graphics card?

Comment: I'd prefer not if you have any other suggestions...  Nope, the issue is occuring on a Samsung Series 9 laptop.

Comment: You could just disable the parts of Compiz you edited, I think is what Jobin meant?

Comment: @Anto, See if CCSM > Utilities > Enable Session Management is Enabled.

Comment: @NoTime I configured it too long ago, I can't remember exactly what's been modified :(

Comment: @Sneetsher Yep, the Utility/Session Management is enabled